# Regular expression search string with parentheses as part of string to detect in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression that I'm iterating over a large number of search terms that I don't control. Is there a way to detect special characters and treat them as part of the search rather than as regular expression terms?

**Edit**
I clarified the question

```
searchTerms = ['ThisIsMySearchString(LSB)', 'OtherSearchTerm']
list = ['ThisIsMySearchString(LSB)OtherStuffInString', 'OtherStringsToSearch']

for item in searchTerms:
    if (re.search(item, list, re.I)):
        print('found item')
```

Comment: It's in the very first lines of the docs of `re`.

Comment: What hinders you to put backslashes into the search term?

Comment: @mkiever I've edited the post to reflect more what I'm looking for. I'm not looking for a hardcoded string, so I have to generalize detecting it somehow.

Comment: I'm iterating through a huge list of search terms, and I have no way of knowing exactly when I hit the one with (LSB) in it. I guess I could use some kind of regular substring check to find it and edit into the search string. But, that's kind of the point of using regular expressions, because it's more flexible than searching for a substring.

Comment: You should add to the question that you do not control the search patterns and that they may contain special characters which you don't want.

Comment: I'ved added clarification to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.escape` on your patterns first and then normally use `re.search`. This assumes that you only have literal patterns and never want any special meaning in the patterns.

```
searchTerms = ['ThisIsMySearchString(LSB)', 'OtherSearchTerm']
list = ['ThisIsMySearchString(LSB)OtherStuffInString', 'OtherStringsToSearch']

for item in searchTerms:
    for targetText in list:
        if (re.search(re.escape(item), targetText, re.I)):
            print('found item', item, 'in', targetText)
```

Comment: This is it. Thanks for helping me clarify what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the `(` in your regex to make it treat it not as a special character but rather one to match. so:

```
re.search('ThisIsMySearchString(LSB)', list, re.I)
```

becomes

```
re.search('ThisIsMySearchString\(LSB\)', list, re.I)
```

In general, you use `\` to escape the special character, like `.` which becomes `\.` if you want to search on it.

**Update**

OK, now with new information, I would try to use Python's powerful batteries included features to find your terms. Something like:

```
searchTerms = ['ThisIsMySearchString(LSB)', 'OtherSearchTerm']
list = ['ThisIsMySearchString(LSB)OtherStuffInString', 'OtherStringsToSearch']

for term in searchTerms:
    for item in list:
        if term in item:
            print(f'Found {term} in the list!')
```

which, for me, gives:

```
Found ThisIsMySearchString(LSB) in the list!
```

Comment: Is there any performance benefit to using this as opposed to using re.escape()?

Comment: Yes. If you are dealing with a very large set, you could turn the above into a generator and save memory.

Comment: I concentrated on fixing the OP, but indeed when you're not dealing with special characters at all this is much simpler and to be preferred.

Comment: Indeed, @mkiever, I was the first to up vote your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply escape the parenthesis with a \.

```
if (re.search('ThisIsMySearchString\(LSB\)', list, re.I)):
```

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect what I'm doing in my code more accurately. The search string isn't hardcoded, so I have to detect that there are parentheses somehow, and flag it appropriately.